# Recurrences related to Ramanujan's 1/pi formulas for level 10?

Tags: recursion, difference-equations, integer-sequence

In the course of my research years ago, I came across **three** integer sequences related to Ramanujan's pi formulas but for level $10$. Their recurrence relations may be important. (Just like the level $6$ version was important for $\zeta(3)$.) Given the binomial numbers,

$$\text{Binomial}[n,m]=\binom n m$$

the first two sequences are,

\begin{align}
A_k = \sum_{j=0}^k \binom {k+j} {k-j} \sum_{m=0}^j \binom {j}{m}^4 &= 1,3,25,267,3249,42795,\dots\\
B_k = \sum_{j=0}^k (-4)^{k-j}\binom {k+j} {k-j} \sum_{m=0}^j \binom {j}{m}^4 &= 1, -2, 10, -68, 514, -4100,\dots
\end{align}

which start with $k=0$, hence $A_0 = B_0 = 1.$ The third one is slightly more complicated,

\begin{align}C_n 
&= \sum_{j=0}^n (-5)^{n-j}\binom {n+j} {n-j} \binom{2j}j \sum_{k=0}^j \binom j k \binom{2k}{k}^{-1} \sum_{m=0}^k \binom{k}{m}^4\\ 
&= 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 23, -263, 1343, -2303,\dots
\end{align}

which start with $n=0$, hence $C_0 = 1.$

The recurrence of the first one is already known and discussed in this ancient [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265688/about-a-ramanujan-sato-formula-of-level-10-a-recurrence-and-zeta5). Since this involves level $10$, perhaps it is not surprising it is a $5$-term recurrence of form,

$$P_1 A_{k}+P_2 A_{k+1}+P_3 A_{k+2}+P_4 A_{k+3}+P_5 A_{k+4} =0$$

where the $P_i = P_i(k)$ are deg-$4$ polynomials in $k$.

---

**Questions**

1. May I know the recurrence relation for $B_k$ and $C_n$, or at least a simple code that will run in an old Mathematica?
2. Given any infinite integer sequence, is there a command in Wolfram Alpha to find the recurrence relation?

Comment: Is this for the Mathematica? I mean the software Mathematica. Or is it perhaps for the Maths.S.E?

Comment: @bmf It is really for this group. I have a very old version of Mathematica and I need to know the command, if any. Or if WolframAlpha can do it so if i have future integer sequences, then i’ll know what to do.

Comment: Perhaps you should stress that you want code for this, because due to the absence of code and the explicit request you can understand the confusion

Comment: @bmf Ok, I will edit the post. Hopefully, my version is up to the task, since it doesn't seem to have $\text{RSolve}$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII You could also maybe use the wolfram cloud or the free wolfram kernel for developers with maybe a Jupyter notebook to have a more recent version but the licence terms would not allow you to publish the result for research as I understand.

Comment: @userrandrand: In the linked MO post, a guy used Maple to find the first recurrence relation using the first few terms of the sequence. Since we now have Wolfram Alpha, can't one just plug in the sequence, and WA's output will be the recurrence relation?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Maybe, for finding the recurrence formula formally without any guesses from the first few values, the function you might be looking for is `DifferenceRootReduce`, for example `DifferenceRootReduce[(n + 1)/(n - 1), n]` works in wolframalpha.

Comment: For finding the formula as a guess from the first few values, you might be looking for `FindSequenceFunction` for example, `FindSequenceFunction[{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13}, n]` works in wolfram alpha

Comment: I tried the functions I mentioned and it seems Mathematica's algorithms can not find the recurrence formula. The code from the answer below might be enough. I asked ChatGPT to translate your LaTeX to Mathematica code, it seems alright but you might want to verify:

Comment: `a[k_] := Sum[Binomial[k + j, k - j] Sum[Binomial[j, m]^4, {m, 0, j}], {j, 0, k}];
b[k_] := Sum[(-4)^(k - j) Binomial[k + j, k - j] Sum[Binomial[j, m]^4, {m, 0, j}], {j, 0, k}];
c[n_] := Sum[(-5)^(n - j) Binomial[n + j, n - j] Binomial[2 j, j] Sum[Binomial[j, k] Binomial[2 k, k]^-1 Sum[Binomial[k, m]^4, {m, 0, k}], {k, 0, j}], {j, 0, n}]`

Comment: @userrandrand: Thanks. In the 2011 paper I read, the author mentioned he simply inputted the level 6 formula (with binomials) into Maple, and the output was a 3-term recurrence relation. I had assumed the newer versions of Mathematica had a command like that. But I am trying Somos' code as we speak.

Comment: @Somos I definitely will try this, as I need to check a lot of sequences. I gave a longer comment below your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question is asking to find linear recurrences with polynomial
coefficients for number sequences. As far as I know, Mathematica
still does not have this functionality builtin. That is the context
of my question
[265844](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/265844/)
"Finding polynomial relations between power series and sequences".

For this important special case, I have written a simple function
that can find linear recurrences with polynomial coefficients. No
doubt the code could be improved and made more robust.

```
findrecur::usage = "findrecur[nterm, ncoef, a, an] tries to find a linear recurrence"<>
" with number of terms (nterm) and polynomial coeffcients up to degree (ncoef-1)"<>
" given a list of numbers (a) whose name is (an).";

findrecur[nterm_Integer, ncoef_Integer, a_List, an_:"a"] := Module[
{nt=nterm, nc=ncoef, nv=Length[a], c, equList, soln, polList, test, gcd},

Print["Sequence ", an, ": number of terms, coefficients, values = ", {nt, nc, nv}];

(* Create list of equations to solve using nv sequence values list a[[]] *)
equList = Table[ 0 == Sum[a[[n+i]] * n^e* c[e,i], {e,0,nc-1}, {i,0,nt-1}], {n,nv-nt}];

(* Solve the linear equations for the polynomial coefficients *)
soln = Solve[equList,Flatten[Table[c[e,i], {e,0,nc-1}, {i,0,nt-1}],1]][[1]] //Quiet;

(* Create the list of polynomials with common factors removed *)
polList = Table[ Sum[ n^e*c[e,i], {e,0,nc-1}], {i,0,nt-1}] /.soln /.{c[0,0]->1};
polList = polList /.{c[_,_]->0} //Factor;

(* Verify the recurrence using the sequence values to be sure *)
If[And@@Table[ 0==Sum[ polList[[i+1]]*a[[n+i]], {i,0,nt-1}], {n,nv-nt}],
    gcd = PolynomialGCD@@polList; If[gcd=!=0, polList/=gcd;
 
(* Return the linear recurrence to be equated to zero *)
    Sum[ polList[[i+1]]*Subscript[an, n+i], {i, 0, nt-1}], "Fail"]]];
```

This function can be used for the given sequence $A_k$ as follows:

```
(* Define the sequence function *)
Ak[k_Integer] := Sum[ Binomial[k+j,k-j]*Sum[Binomial[j,m]^4, {m,0,j}], {j,0,k}];

(* Output the first few values as a check *)
Print["A(0..)", " = ",Table[ Ak[k], {k,0,5}]];

(* Call the function to find a polynomial recurrence *)
0 == findrecur[5, 5, Table[Ak[k], {k,1,30}], "A"] //TeXForm

(* A(0..) = {3,25,267,3249,42795} *)
(* Sequence A: number of terms, coefficients, values = {5,5,30} *)
```

$$ 0=(n+3) (n+1)^3 \text{A}_n\\
   +\left(-20 n^4-152 n^3-420 n^2-508 n-229\right)
   \text{A}_{n+1}\\+\left(38 n^4+380 n^3+1416 n^2+2330 n+1431\right)
   \text{A}_{n+2}\\+\left(-20 n^4-248 n^3-1140 n^2-2292
   n-1689\right) \text{A}_{n+3}\\
   +(n+2)(n+4)^3 \text{A}_{n+4} $$

This returns a $5$ term recurrence with degree $4$ coefficients.
An alternative recurrence for this sequence is returned using:

```
(* Call the function to find a polynomial recurrence *)
0 == findrecur[6, 4, Table[Ak[k], {k,1,29}], "A"] //TeXForm

(* Sequence A: number of terms, coefficients, values = {6,4,29} *)
```

$$ 0=(n+1)^3 \text{A}_n\\-3 \left(7 n^3+33 n^2+53 n+29\right)
\text{A}_{n+1}\\+2 \left(29
   n^3+219 n^2+549 n+460\right) \text{A}_{n+2}\\-2 \left(29 n^3+303
   n^2+1053 n+1214\right) \text{A}_{n+3}\\+3 \left(7 n^3+93 n^2+413
   n+613\right) \text{A}_{n+4}\\-(n+5)^3
   \text{A}_{n+5} $$

**N.B.** The sequence values used begin with $A_1$ due to the $0^0$
feature of Mathematica.

**N.B.** I edited the `TeXForm` output a bit to improve readability.

You can use similar code for the $B_k$ and $C_k$ sequences
by changing the sequence definition. The results for both of them:

```
(* Define the sequence function *)
Bk[k_Integer] := Sum[(-4)^(k-j)*Binomial[k+j,k-j]*
   Sum[Binomial[j, m]^4, {m,0,j}],{j,0,k}];

(* Output the first few values as a check *)
Print["B(0..)", " = ",Table[ Bk[k], {k,0,5}]];

(* Call the function to find a polynomial recurrence *)
0 == findrecur[5, 5, Table[Bk[k], {k,1,29}], "B"] //TeXForm

(* B(0..) = {1,-2,10,-68,514,-4100} *)
(* Sequence B: number of terms, coefficients, values = {5,5,29} *)
```

$$ 0=256 (n+3) (n+1)^3 \text{B}_n\\
   +32 \left(10 n^4+79 n^3+230 n^2+296 n+143\right) \text{B}_{n+1}\\
   +4\left(32 n^4+320 n^3+1199 n^2+1995 n+1244\right)
   \text{B}_{n+2}\\+2 \left(10 n^4+121 n^3+545 n^2+1079 n+788\right)
   \text{B}_{n+3}\\+(n+2) (n+4)^3
   \text{B}_{n+4} $$

```
(* Call the function to find a polynomial recurrence *)
0 == findrecur[6, 4, Table[Bk[k], {k,1,29}], "B"] //TeXForm

(* Sequence B: number of terms, coefficients, values = {6,4,29} *)
```

$$ 0=1024(n+1)^3 \text{B}_n\\
   +128 \left(12 n^3+63 n^2+113 n+69\right) \text{B}_{n+1}\\+16
   \left(52 n^3+402 n^2+1047 n+920\right) \text{B}_{n+2}\\+4
   \left(52 n^3+534 n^2+1839 n+2122\right) \text{B}_{n+3}\\+2
   \left(12 n^3+153 n^2+653 n+933\right) \text{B}_{n+4}\\+(n+5)^3
   \text{B}_{n+5} $$

```
(* Define the sequence function *)
Ck[n_Integer] := Sum[ (-5)^(n-j)*Binomial[n+j,n-j]*Binomial[2*j,j]*
  Sum[ Binomial[j,k]/Binomial[2*k,k]*
     Sum[ Binomial[k, m]^4, {m, 0, k}],{k, 0, j}],{j, 0, n}];

(* Output the first few values as a check *)
Print["C(1..)", " = ",Table[ Ck[k], {k,0,5}]];

(* Call the function to find a polynomial recurrence *)
0 == findrecur[7, 4, Table[Ck[k], {k,1,34}], "C"] //TeXForm

(* C(1..) = {1,-1,1,-1,1,23} *)
(* Sequence C: number of terms, coefficients, values = {7,4,34} *)
```

$$ 0=15625 (n+1)^3 \text{C}_n\\  
   +625\left(18 n^3+99 n^2+185 n+117\right) \text{C}_{n+1}\\
   +25\left(183 n^3+1464 n^2+3966 n+3638\right) \text{C}_{n+2}\\
   +2 (2 n+7) \left(279 n^2+1953 n+3523\right) \text{C}_{n+3}\\
   +\left(183 n^3+2379 n^2+10371 n+15157\right)
   \text{C}_{n+4}\\+\left(18 n^3+279 n^2+1445 n+2501\right)
   \text{C}_{n+5}\\+(n+6)^3 \text{C}_{n+6} $$

---

I think it is worth improving the previous versions of my code.
Here is the latest iteration:

```
findseqrecur::usage =
"findseqrecur[nt, nc, a, ao, an, n, no] finds linear recurrences with"<>
" number of terms (nt) and polynomial coeffcients up to degree (nc-1)"<>
" given a list of numbers (a ={an[ao], an[ao+1], ...) indexed by (n)"<>
" of the form sum_{i..nt} p_i(n)an_{n+no+i}.";

findseqrecur[nt_Integer, nc_Integer, a_List, ao_:1, an_:"a", n_:n, no_:0] :=
Module[{ nv=Length[a], io=1, c, equs, sols, vars, polys, recurs},

Print["Sequence ", an, ": number of terms, coefficients, values = ", {nt, nc, nv}];

(* Create list of equations to solve using nv sequence values list a[[]] *)
equs = Table[ 0 == Sum[a[[k+i]]*(k+ao)^e*c[e,i], {e,0,nc-1}, {i,1,nt}], {k,0,nv-nt}];

(* Solve the linear equations for the polynomial coefficients *)
sols = Solve[equs, Flatten[Table[c[e, i], {e,0,nc-1}, {i,1,nt}],1]][[1]] //Quiet;

(* Find a non-zero coefficients in solution *)
vars = Sort[Variables[sols[[All, 2]]]];

polys = Table[ Table[ Sum[ (n+ao)^e * c[e, i], {e, 0, nc-1}], {i, 1, nt}]
      /. sols /. {cvar -> 1} /. {c[_, _] -> 0}, {cvar, vars}];
      
recurs = Table[ Which[
    0 != Normal@Sum[ a[[n+i]] * poly[[i]], {i, 1, nt}, {n, 0, nv-nt}], Nothing,
    0 === (gcd = PolynomialGCD@@poly), Nothing,
    True, Sum[ Factor[poly[[i]]/gcd/.{n -> n+no+1-ao}] *Subscript[an, n+no+i],
       {i, 1, nt}] ], {poly, polys}];
        
DeleteDuplicates[ Flatten@recurs, (#1 == #2 || Simplify[#1 == -#2])&]];
```

This version returns a list of recursions instead of only a single one.
For example:

```
(* Define the sequence function *)
Ak[k_Integer] := Sum[ Binomial[k+j,k-j]*Sum[Binomial[j,m]^4, {m,0,j}], {j,0,k}];

(* Output the first few values as a check *)
Print["A(0..) = ",Table[ Ak[k], {k,0,5}]];

(* Call the function to find a polynomial recurrence *)
result = (0 == #&) /@ findseqrecur[6, 4, Array[Ak, 28, 1], 1, "A", k, -4];

(* Verify the result recursion equations *)
And @@ Flatten @ Table[ Simplify[result/.{Subscript["A",i_]->Ak[i]}], {k,4}]

(* Output the result equations in TeX form *)
result //TeXForm

(* A(0..) = {1,3,25,267,3249,42795} *)
(* True *)

(* Sequence A: number of terms, coefficients, values = {6,4,28} *)
```

$$
\left\{0=+(k-2)^3 \text{A}_{k-3} \\
-3 \left(7 k^3-30 k^2+44 k-22\right) \text{A}_{k-2} \\
+2 \left(29 k^3-42 k^2+18 k+1\right) \text{A}_{k-1} \\
-2 \left(29 k^3+42 k^2+18 k-1\right) \text{A}_k \\
+3 \left(7 k^3+30 k^2+44 k+22\right) \text{A}_{k+1} \\
-(k+2)^3 \text{A}_{k+2}\right\}
$$

Notice the skew-symmetry. The code could be further improved I think.

**N.B.** If the number of sequence values In parameter `a` is not
sufficient to determine the coefficients uniquely, then the function
may return large coefficients. You should call the function again
with more sequence values and compare the returned coefficients to
confirm that they are valid. Also, verify the results as in the
previous example. As a very simple exercise try the code

```
Table[ findseqrecur[2, 2, Array[Factorial, nv]], {nv, 4}]
```

which shows the effect of using bigger values of `nv`. This also
shows a slight glitch in my code which I may be able to fix later.

Comment: Thanks! I finally found the closed-form of the last three level 10 sequences. (I actually found them late 2019, then Covid-19 interrupted.)

Comment: Beautiful, it works! (However, I had to use the labels "ord" and "deg" because of the commands "Order" and "Degree". And my version didn't have the command "Quiet", but I figured the code will work without it.)

Comment: You may be interested in this new [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446654/12905). It uses these three sequences (plus a fourth one) to tie together four eta quotients.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII About "order" and "degree". Yes, the symbols "Order" and "Degree" already have built-in meaning in Mathematica, but the Wolfram Language is case-sensitive so using "order" and "degree" should not cause any problem. I will look at you MO post.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Thanks for that comment! I have more comments in the code and I slightly modified the code. In the case you mention, I suggest to try `order = 3; degree = 4; values = 11;` as the minimum. No doubt, the code should be more robust.

Comment: For the latest sequence, if interested, its context is in this [new MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446948/12905).

Comment: Thank you so much for this! First, I'm already working on the level-18 sequences and I am curious about how high the number of terms will get. Second, I've seen some 4-term recurrences and I want to experiment if they can be reduced to a 3-term one. As I've recently discovered, they can be used to generate nice continued fractions.